# How do you automatically install puppet modules on `puppet apply`

Tags: puppet, vagrant

Is it possible to automatically install or include puppet modules in your puppet config? I'm having to manually run `puppet module install` before running `puppet apply`.

Comment: What's in your configuration? And why are you running the commands yourself? Are you not using a puppet master server?

Comment: No master server. I'm running a vagrant development server. It seems like I'm forced to run `puppet module install` before including a module in my config file. Can't you just use puppet config to install modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm downloading modules and storing them in a directory above my `Vagrantfile` in which I've specified the path to find modules using `config.vm.provision :puppet, :module_path => "modules"` and then including them in my puppet manifest.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's not possible with 'vanilla' Puppet, but with [librarian-puppet](http://librarian-puppet.com/) it's possible:

> Librarian-puppet is a bundler for your puppet infrastructure. You can use librarian-puppet to manage the puppet modules your infrastructure depends on. It is based on Librarian, a framework for writing bundlers, which are tools that resolve, fetch, install, and isolate a project's dependencies.
>
> Librarian-puppet manages your modules/ directory for you based on your Puppetfile. Your Puppetfile becomes the authoritative source for what modules you require and at what version, tag or branch.
>
> Once using Librarian-puppet you should not modify the contents of your modules directory. The individual modules' repos should be updated, tagged with a new release and the version bumped in your Puppetfile.

Answer (score 0):

As for now, `Vagrant` has [vagrant-librarian-puppet](https://github.com/mhahn/vagrant-librarian-puppet) module.

Installation:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-librarian-puppet
```

From readme:

> Vagrant will automatically run Librarian-Puppet before any
>   provisioning step, so simply set up your Puppetfile as you normally
>   would.
>
> You may specify the subdirectory within which to run librarian-puppet
>   using the librarian_puppet.puppetfile_dir config key. Please keep in
>   mind that you will need to explicitly set the modules path in the
>   :puppet provisioner and this path must exist before running vagrant
>   commands.